# How to locate Oracle EBS fields in the database?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

I have a Oracle EBS form like so:

[image]

And I want to locate what are the names of the columns in the DB that pertain to these fields.

I have this so far, for a "Requst ID" column:

```
select * from HHS_UMX_REG_REQUESTS WHERE reg_request_id = 261499
```

Does anyone have any general tips/tricks to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to an 11 system but I think the same on R12:
When you create a worklist access grant it will add a record to the `FND_GRANTS` table.
The `Name` field is querying both `FND_USER` and `PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F` because you have to have a valid employee assignment to be eligible for workflow.
`Start Date` would come out of the `FND_GRANTS` table `START_DATE` column.
If you don't specify an `END_DATE` it will place a `null` in that column.
You can also delete the worklist access privilege from the grantee which doesn't place a date in the `END_DATE` column it actually deletes the record from `FND_GRANTS`.

Now for protips on how to find what tables your OA Framework pages are hitting:
[Enable FND Diagnostics](https://oracleappsnotes.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/enabling-access-to-oracle-forms-based-applications-diagnostics-menu/) for your user (and your user alone)
In the bottom left part of the screen you'll see a link called `About this page`, click that.
When you are in the about screen in the middle you'll see something similar to `Business Component References Details`
In here you'll see objects like `oracle.apps.fnd.wf.worklist.server.GrantersListVO` for example
Click on that and you'll actually get the version and SQL its using to query the data.
Example:

```
SELECT GRANT_GUID,
  GRANTEE_KEY,
  START_DATE,
  END_DATE,
  PARAMETER1 AS granter_key,
  PARAMETER2,
  PARAMETER3,
  PARAMETER4,
  PARAMETER5,
  PARAMETER6,
  PARAMETER7,
  PARAMETER8,
  PARAMETER9,
  PARAMETER10,
  wf_directory.GetRoleDisplayName(PARAMETER1) AS granter_display_name
FROM FND_GRANTS
WHERE MENU_ID                = :1
AND OBJECT_ID                = :2
AND INSTANCE_SET_ID          = :3
AND GRANTEE_KEY              = :4
AND INSTANCE_TYPE            = 'SET'
AND START_DATE              <= sysdate
AND NVL(END_DATE, sysdate ) >= sysdate
UNION
SELECT SYS_GUID(),
  NULL,
  TO_DATE(NULL),
  TO_DATE(NULL),
  FND_GLOBAL.USER_NAME,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  wf_directory.GetRoleDisplayName(FND_GLOBAL.USER_NAME)
FROM dual
;
```